# Importing a cssnext custom properties set in to a CSS module

Tags: css, postcss, css-modules, cssnext

I have a file, typography.css, containing a cssnext [Custom Property](http://cssnext.io/features/#custom-properties-var) (`--headingColor`), a cssnext [Custom Properties Set](http://cssnext.io/features/#custom-properties-set-apply) (`--heading`), a [`@value`](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules-values), a global element style (`h1`) and a CSS class (`.heading`):

```
:root {
  --headingColor: #f00;
  --heading {
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    color: --headingColor;
  }
}

@value headingColor: #f00;

h1 {
  @apply --heading;
}

.heading {
  @apply --heading;
}
```

Using postcss I can use the @value and compose the class in a CSS module without including the `h1` and `.heading` class in the outputted CSS:

```
@value headingColor from "typography.css";
.moduleHeading {
  composes: heading from "typography.css";
}
```

However, using cssnext features, how can I do the same thing with the `--heading` and `--headingColor`, without outputting the `h1` style and `.heading` class?